# Isolating a subject with rotobrush tool and then create Light wrap

Tags: after-effects

I am trying to create a light wrap on an isolated subject using the technic explained on the tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qR7V-4ZlW0E  It uses a channele effect which equals the source of all channels to the background. It then uses a gaussian blur, inverts and makes two CC composites. I can't really explain why the person does that as I am no expert. My proble is that I don't know how he got the subjects isolated. I am trying to isolate the subject on the same layer using the rotobrush tool and its not working right.

Anyone knows how to get an isolated subject with the rotobrush tool, removing completly the background.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Rotobrush has created the transparency you want by clicking on the transparency grid in the comp panel. You should see the grid where there is transparency. You can also use the Channel menu to view the Alpha.